# Anti-spam filtering in Exchange 2016 almost doesn't work

Tags: exchange, spam, exchange-2016

I have fresh installation Exchange 2016. I know that content filtering is depreciated since November 2016, and in some future we'll have to use EOP.

So far I've read, content filtering in Exchange and Outlook should be the same - but content filtering in Exchange, with latest definitions, constantly classifies apparent spam messages with very low SCL, 1 or 2, in rare cases 4 or 5. Outlook itself all such messages correctly filters as junk mail.

Is there anything I can do with Exchange content filter, so the result is at least similar to what Outlook does?

Comment: I would setup an SpamAssassin in Front of your Exchange. It is super easy and keeps away a lot of spam and such stuff.